# I want to cycle through users and only print the information when the directory exists - BASH

Tags: linux, bash

I'm trying to cycle through all users on the system, and print only the users who have the directory .junkdir in their Home (The end product of this, is that only my group profiles will have the directory, and I want to total the disk usage for that directory for all users together - I will sort that after I sort this problem)

Can somebody advise where I'm going wrong?

```
#Function to list total usage of all users in bytes
{
 #Get list of all users in aphabetical order
 get_users="$(getent passwd | cut -d: -f1 | sort)"

 IFS=$'\n' #Use newline as delimiter for for-loop
 for user_usage in $get_users
  if [ -d /home/"$user_usage"/.junkdir ]; then
    do
      #Do processing on each line
      echo 'Username:' $user_usage 
      echo 'Usage(bytes):' "$(du -h --bytes /home/"$user_usage"/.junkdir)"
      echo '********************************'
    done
  fi
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you need that IFS edit. Personally, I *would* set IFS, but not use the variable, and pull field 6 for the dir because it might not be in /home.

```
IFS=: 
while read usr x x x x home x
do if [[ -d $home/.junkdir ]] 
   then echo "Username: $usr"
        echo "Usage(bytes): $(du -h --bytes $home/.junkdir)"
        echo '********************************'
   fi
done < /etc/passwd
```

Comment: .junkdir is basically a directory that I send files I want to delete to. Only human users are going to have the .junkdir directory added, so I'm really wanting to filter out all the other users. Thats why I've been trying to implement it the way I have. You have to excuse my ignorance, I'm just struggling to see how I would change my code to your suggestions.

Comment: Try that. We could also add a threshold and automatic removal of oldest files first if you wanted to get ambitious. ;)

Answer (score 1):

You could be better off using the 6th field, which is the home folder of the user, rather than guessing they are all in /home/

Comment: Sorry I've only just learning BASH. I'm aware that only a few of the users are in the /home/, I was under the impression that checking that the .junkdir directory exists would filter these out? Thats what I'm looking for help for.